# Clean architecture: requester stereotype

Tags: clean-architecture

I'm reading Robert C. Martin, Clean Architecture book.

He shows this diagram:

[image]

A piece that caught my attention is FinancialReport`Requester`, stereotype.

Is this the use-case?

He use this interface in order to avoud transitive dependencies between `Controller` and business entities.

Some of you can tell me what are he talking about those transitive dependenices?

Answer (score 0):

The requester is an interface defined in the use case layer through which a controller can interact with the use case. It is also called "input port" in this book and it is implemented by the use case.
This interface ensures that the controller does not know the use case implementation directly.